# Names of constructors and destructors of templates

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constructor

From [n4459](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4459.html):

> **635. Names of constructors and destructors of templates**
>
> There is a discrepancy between the syntaxes allowed for defining a
>   constructor and a destructor of a class template. For example:
>
> ```
> template <class> struct S { S(); ~S (); };
> template <class T> S<T>::S<T>() { }        // error
> template <class T> S<T>::~S<T>() { }       // okay
> ```
>
> The reason for this is that 3.4.3.1 [class.qual] paragraph 2 says that
>   **S::S is “considered to name the constructor,” which is not a template and thus cannot accept a template argument list.** On the
>   other hand, the second S in `S::~S` finds the injected-class-name, which
>   “can be used with or without a template-argument-list” (14.6.1
>   [temp.local] paragraph 1) and thus satisfies the requirement to name
>   the destructor's class (12.4 [class.dtor] paragraph 1).

I don't understand, What does say **that `S::S` is “considered to name the constructor,” which is not a template**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> S::S is “considered to name the constructor,” which is not a template and thus cannot accept a template argument list

Yes, it is possibly because a constructor *might* be templated. So by preventing non-template constructor to *not* have `S<T>::S<T>` syntax, the language reserves this syntax for the templated constructor.

Here is an example:

```
template <typename T> 
struct X 
{ 
   template<typename U>
   X(); 
  ~X (); 
};

template <typename T> 
template <typename U> 
X<T>::X<U>() { }        //OK now

template <class T>
X<T>::~X<T>() { }       // okay
```

If the syntax `S<T>::S<T>()` was allowed, then in this case you would have to write `X<T>::X<T><U>()` — that is an ugly and a **new** syntax. So in a sense, by preventing this, the syntax is slightly cleaner and that also avoids introducing a *new* syntax.

On the other hand, the destructor can *never* be a template.